# How to set heigth of a div to 100% height of the outer div?

Tags: html, css

I have two cascading divs. The outer div should have a width of 100% screen width and for example a height of 60/70px.

The inner div should be centrally positioned and has a height of 100% of the outer div. I am trying it out, but couldn't solve it. Has anyone an idea what's wrong with my CSS?

This is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mncgkf09/3/

Extract:

HTML

```
<div class="section header-wrapper">

<div class="section-inner header">

<div id="nav" style="border: none;">
                <div class="ln-logo"><a href="http://localhost/wp">My Blog</a></div>
                <!-- The Hamburger Menu Icon #begin# -->
                <div class="ln-hamburger" onclick="toggle_ln_nav()">
                    <div class="hamburger">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cross">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>                
                </div>
                <!-- The Hamburger Menu Icon #end# -->
            
                <div class="ln-nav" style="display: block; border-bottom: thin solid rgb(136, 136, 136);">
                    <ul id="ln-nav-items" class="ln-nav-items"><li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-96 ln-nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/wp/topic/apple/" class="ln-nav-item-link">Apple</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-95 ln-nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/wp/topic/uncategorized/" class="ln-nav-item-link">Uncategorized</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-94 ln-nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/wp/topic/aws/" class="ln-nav-item-link">AWS</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-97 ln-nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/wp/topic/Google/" class="ln-nav-item-link">Google</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-129" class="menu-item menu-item-129 ln-nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/wp/sample-page/" class="ln-nav-item-link">About</a></li>
</ul>                </div>
            </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color:red;
  height: 60px;
}

.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
}

#nav {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9997;
    background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.9);
    border-bottom: thin solid #888;
}

.ln-logo {
    color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

    .ln-logo a, .ln-logo a:visited {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
    }

    .ln-logo a:hover {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
    }

.ln-nav {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.9);
    display: none;
    border-bottom: thin solid #fff;
}

.ln-nav-items {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.ln-nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

    .ln-nav li:last-child {
        border: none;
    }

    .ln-nav li a, .ln-nav li a:visited {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        border: none;
    }

        .ln-nav li a:hover {
            font-weight: 400;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: inherit;
            /* background-color: rgba(237, 237, 237, 0.95); */
        }



.ln-hamburger {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 40px;
    /* height:40px; */
    /* border:1px solid rgb(15,15,15); */
    /* cursor:pointer; */
    position: relative;
}



.hamburger, .cross {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

    .hamburger span {
        display: block;
        width: 18px;
        height: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

        .hamburger span:last-child {
            margin: 0;  
        }

        .hamburger span:before, .hamburger span:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgb(15,15,15);
            transform: translateX(-200%);
            transition: transform ease 300ms;
        }

        .hamburger span:after {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }

        .hamburger span:nth-child(2):before, .hamburger span:nth-child(2):after {
            transition-delay: 75ms;
        }

        .hamburger span:last-child:before, .hamburger span:last-child:after {
            transition-delay: 150ms;
        }

        .menu-toggle:hover .hamburger span:before {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }

        .menu-toggle:hover .hamburger span:after {
            transform: translateX(200%);
        }

        .menu-toggle.active .hamburger span:before {
            transform: translateX(100%);
        }

        .menu-toggle.active .hamburger span:after {
            transform: translateX(200%);
        }

        .cross span {
            display: block;
            width: 18px;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: rgb(15,15,15);
            transform: translateY(50%) rotate(45deg) scaleX(0);
            transition: transform ease 200ms;
        }

            .cross span:last-child {
                transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scaleX(0);
            }

        .menu-toggle.active .cross span {
            transition-delay: 450ms;
            transform: translateY(50%) rotate(45deg) scaleX(1);
        }

        .menu-toggle.active .cross span:last-child {
            transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scaleX(1);
        }
```

Comment: are you referring to the `#nav`? set its height to 100%

Comment: But then the problem is, that on toggling the menu by clicking on th ehamburger icon, the #nav height gets smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `height: 100%;` to your `#nav` element in CSS will do.

By the way, you can consider using CSS lint tools like [this](http://csslint.net/) to help improve your CSS code.

Try replace your `#nav` with this:

```
#nav {
    /* position: -webkit-sticky; // unnecessary & duplicate */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9997;
    background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.9);
    border-bottom: thin solid #888;
    height: 100%;
}
```

check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4mbLozp/1/) for a fix. Your navbar needs another div outside the logo and hamburger to keep its height. You may need to tweak the styles a bit, but the height issue is solved.

Comment: But then the problem is, that on toggling the menu by clicking on the hamburger icon, the #nav height gets smaller.

Comment: @SEKTOR8 I updated the answer and you can refer to the link for the solution. We need another div in the nav to keep the height.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help. I need to "compare" your and my css to understand which changes you made, so i can learn from it.